# Java Grande SOR multithreaded benchmark

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a question about SOR (successive over relaxation). I know that SOR can be described as N*N grid and you perform n iterations over the grid and you can report the execution time. This benchmark has an outer loop over iterations and two inner loop. The inner loop is used to update each value of the grid, but the value of the grid needs neighbors in the calculation, so it's kind of serial execution. My question is to allow parallelism , I have to know if I will run each iteration in a thread (), or I will run each  row on a thread. Can anyone guide me which loop should have parallelism ?

Comment: The inner loops need the neighbour values from the previous pass, right?

Comment: Yes, to be more concise ..it needs the previous value and next one in its row

Comment: The values it needs to the left and right are the values from the previous iteration?  It sounds like a convolution filter.  How big is the grid?  Usually, multi-threading - and the heavyweight locking/synchronizing this would involve - only benefits *big* problems.  If you have only a few million points, it probably doesn't help to use threads.

Comment: Yes, from previous iteration.. The idea is that I want to apply work-stealing algorithm in such a problem whatever the grid is .. the minimum will be 1000*1000 and will be increased to measure the speedup.. The actual implementation is exist in threading but in a complex way that I couldn't understand it well. If you want to have a look, you can check Multithreaded-benchmarks on that link 
http://www2.epcc.ed.ac.uk/computing/research_activities/java_grande/index_1.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a 2D array and the values only depend on other values in the same row; no values in a row depends on any values in a column.

This means that rows can be computed in isolation to each other, to the full number of passes.

As the values in the middle of a row depends on the computation of the whole row in the previous pass, its very hard to share the work in computing a row.  A work-stealing queue of spans within a row, operating within a pass, would be a lot of coordination overhead for such a cheap actual task.  It seems too fine-grained to be distributed.

Therefore, a row is a natural work unit.  You could have a work-stealing queue of rows.